# Manage storage in 16 GB Windows tablet

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I have a windows tablet with 16 GB internal storage and 2 gigs of ram. 
The model is here: [link](https://www.iball.co.in/DemoSite/WQ32Layout.aspx#iBallSlideWQ32). I cannot download windows updates since I don't have the free 8 GB, they are asking. I don't have any of my user files stored, apart from a single software-Sumatra pdf reader. Still, I only have 2 GB of free space. I have a 64 GB SD card. Is there any way to convert sd card storage to merge with internal storage, so that I can increase the total internal storage of (OS) drive from 16 GB to (16+64) 80 GB?
I believe the disc speed may become slow, but if it is not very much slower, then it will be ok. Can anyone please help me with this or do you have any other solution?

Comment: I Just wanted to know if there is any way to merge the sd card storage to the internal storage so it will look like one single storage entity to the windows operating system. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could mount your SD card under one folder under Drive C: via mount point.
There is a guide for you.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/assign-a-mount-point-folder-path-to-a-drive

Comment: Thanks, but I have already done that. While accessing sd card, okay, it will show as part of C drive. But will it really work the other way? LIke still, I am not able to see the C partition extended as 16+64 GB. I Just wanted to know if  there is any way to add the sd card storage to the internal storage so it will look like one single storage entity to the windows operating system.